# Чем приятен дым отечества?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, литература

Честно говоря, со школьных времен меня озадачивала фраза Чацкого: "А дым отечества нам сладок и приятен". Понятие "дым отечества" у меня ассоциировалось с пожарищем, с сожженными домами, что придает совершенно другой характер этой фразе.
Почему Грибоедов сказал именно о дыме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отличный вопрос, спасибо. Над ним не одно поколение лингвистов голову ломало, почему Грибоедов взял в качестве символа отечества именно дым. Аллюзии на Державина и прочих Неронов — это, конечно, хорошо, но как-то не вяжется. Тут-то смысл другой.

Но я не о них сейчас, не о лингвистах и не о неронах. Если Вы склонны видеть в дыме пожарища и проч., то, возможно, Вам будет близко вот [это](http://rupoem.ru/asadov/kak-los-oxripshij.aspx). Должен сказать, что Асадов — не самый мой любимий автор, поэтому не комментирую.

А вот если взять вполне любимого мной Тютчева

«И дым отечества нам сладок и приятен!» —
Так поэтически век прошлый говорит.
А в наш — и сам талант всё ищет в солнце пятен,
И смрадным дымом он отечество коптит!

Я опускаю ссылки на Симонова и Паустовского, хотя у них тоже свое виденье этого дыма.

Что же до фразы Чацкого, то она, как и почти все у Грибоедова, войдя в собрание афоризмов, несколько изменила смысл. Дым ведь далеко не всегда и не у всех ассоциировался с пожаром. Сравните, например, у Матусовского:

Дымилась роща под горою,
И вместе с ней горел закат.

У степных народов дым — это жильё, уют... Степной пожар пахнет совсем по-другому. В чем я лично, кстати, мог убедиться, проведя в раннем отрочестве год в монгольской степи (формально не в юрте, но по сути — почти). Очень бы хотелось списать фразу Чацкого на этот домашний уют. Но есть одно НО. Чацкий (как и сам Грибоедов) всё-таки вполне себе благополучный класс, в *черных* избах не живали. Почему у него дым — символ отечества?

Я лично вижу тут связь не столько с уютом, сколько с процессом горения. "Гореть/светить ради отечества" — вот это откуда. Такое понимание всегда было близко "русскому духу" (кстати, тоже переосмысленное выражение). Сравните хотя бы со "светильником разума". Поэтому и дым сладок и приятен.

Comment: А может попроще. У нас топили дровами - на Западе уже углём, соответственно и дым был разным. Другое дело, что подобное соображение хоть могло подразумеваться, но без цитат Державина тут всё равно не обойтись.

Comment: Уголь-  во времена Грибоедова? Не знаю, не знаю... Но не в том дело.
Я же писал, что в курсе и Державина, и версии про "дым = жильё" со всеми вытекающими (в т.ч. предложенного Вами  уголь vs дрова). Наверное она имеет право на существование, хотя и не без вопросов. Но зачем повторять?
Вообще подробно про историю дыма - [здесь][1]

Насчет "не обойтись" - не знаю. Обходятся как-то многие комментаторы Грибоедова.  

[1]: http://www.bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/9/18.htm

Answer (score 9):

У выражения «Дым отечества» долгая история. Крылатым его сделал Грибоедов, вложивший в уста Чацкого слова: «Когда ж постранствуешь, воротишься домой, / И дым отечества нам сладок и приятен». Последний стих – не вполне точная цитата из стихотворения Гаврилы Романовича Державина «Арфа»: «Мила нам добра весть о нашей стороне: / Отечества и дым нам сладок и приятен». Державин мог отталкиваться от латинской пословицы «Сладок дым отечества», родившейся из «Понтийских посланий» Овидия. Римский поэт, тосковавший в изгнании по родине, мечтал «видеть хоть дым с отечественных очагов». Родная земля влечет к себе человека, пленив его какою-то невыразимою сладостью». В строках Овидия слышен отзвук стихов Гомера. Именно его герой, Одиссей, первым сказал, что «для него сладостна самая смерть, лишь бы только в виду дыма, убегающего с кровель его родины».

Answer (score 2):

Есть маленькая разница в стихах Державина и цитате из него у Грибоедова.
Эта разница передаёт разницу смыслов.
У Державина: "Отчества и дым нам сладок и приятен". Означает, если прозою: "Даже дым, в целом не очень приятная, едкая вещь, приятен, если связан с Отечеством, с Родиной". Можно дать и другое, но близкое толкование. "Даже столь эфемерная вещь, как дым, приятна, если напоминает о Родине. Т.е. дым используется как негатив, что только усиливает смысл (тоска по родине).
У Грибоедова слова переставлены и смысл изменился. Дым просто ассоциируется с Отечеством, только позитив. Такое смещение объяснимо: фраза вложена в уста героя и Грибоедов, во-первых, не отвечает за него (Чацкий просто неточно вспомнил), во-вторых, немного снижает пафос, что естественно для комедии. Есть и логика "ошибки памяти" Чацкого. В контексте своего возвращения, он выбрал позитивный вариант прочтения.
Что же до пожарищ, то этот дым совсем не подразумевался. Это ассоциации века 20-го. Аристократический класс России на стыке 18 и 19 вв. был далёк от этого.

Answer (score 1):

Под словом "дым" часто подразумевали "дом" (подымная подать, вспомните!). То есть дым - это вид, расширенно - пейзаж. Это с одной стороны.
С другой - при сгорании некоторых пород трав, деревьев и кустарников (вспомним хотя бы тимьян, он же фимиам) дым имеет отчетливо обоняемый сладковатый оттенок.
А проще всего это обосновала одна моя знакомая бабуська: "Хоть засратое, да своё!"

Answer (score 1):

Друзья, а мне кажется, что всё гораздо проще! :)
Вы когда-нибудь дышали дымом? Делать это невозможно, он горький, схватывает дыхание, в общем - не приятно. А Чацкий же нам говорит, что на родине всё любимо. И что даже противный дым нам "сладок и приятен".

Answer (score 0):

Если обобщить образно, то дым отечества в данном случае подразумевает особое состояние души, набор сложных эмоции, вызванных умственной деятельностью, не затрагивающий отдел удовольствия, но в высоконравственной личности подразумевается как есть хорошо. И это образно. Еще проще — патриотизм, тоска по Родине. Если в частном случае, то да, топили избы раньше дровами, от этого запах особенный, кому-то детство напоминает счастливое.